# Синхронное прокручивание Listview и ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview, synchronized

У меня есть два элемента: Listview, который находится по правой стороне экрана, и ScrollView, который заполняет оставшуюся часть. Мне надо, чтобы при прокрутке одного из них синхронно прокручивалась и другая часть.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: это сделать не сложно, но очень много возможных путей. Вы бы лучше подробней описали смысл вашей реализации и показали разметку. Мне кажется у Вашей задачи изначально неверный подход; если это не так, то решение становится проще, вам необходимо просто связать два слушателя элементов прокрутки, или отслеживать движение у родительского класса и отдавать данные в слушатели этих элементов, как вариант.

Comment: @Shwarz Andrei , почему изначально неверный подход. У меня слева, listView элемент со списком студентов. Справа таблица, с оценками этих студентов, которая является дочерней для ScrollView. Мне надо прокручивать эти два элемента синхронно, в не зависимести от того, какой из них крутится.

Comment: в listView делаете разметку, с разделителями, где вторая часть (оценки) как будто, то же скрол, будет выглядеть один в один, сделайте на него эффект transation и будет выглядеть, что вторая часть немного отстает и как будто прокручивается, выглядеть будет красиво а самое главное будет работать быстрей и вы можете избежать ряд ошибок, если будете пилить свой велосипед для синхронизации двух скролов, хотя это тоже сделать не очень сложно.

Answer (score 2):

Вот как то так:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                тут логика для опеределения положения во втором списке
                второй_list_view.smoothScrollToPosition(нужная позиция);
            }
        });
```

Если второй элемент ScrollView

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                тут логика для опеределения нужных координат на которые необходимо прокрутить scrollView
                ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrl);
                sv.scrollTo(координата по X, координата по Y);
            }
        });
```

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438061/can-i-scroll-a-scrollview-programmatically-in-android) можно подробнее об этом почитать

Comment: Спасибо, но вы указали изменения для двух Listview. А у меня один Listview и один ScrollView.

Comment: Добавил для ScrollView