# Одновременная (синхронная) прокрутка троих ScrollView

Tags: c#, android-scrollview

Здравствуйте. Есть пользовательский интерфейс, в котором отображени три элемента ScrollView. Как сделать синхронную одновременную прокрутку всех троих ScrollView в не зависимости от того, какой из них пользователь будет прокручивать? 
Желательно описать как это сделать в C# (Xamarin) или просто напишите логику с примером, думаю разберусь. 
Спасибо :)

Comment: логика примерно такая же, как и описано тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489290/199793, то есть Вам на каждом из них надо зарегистрировать `OnScrollListener`, в каждом из которых будут программно скролиться 2 других. С понимаем ООП это можно сделать очень даже красиво =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ !!!

```
        _ScrollViewLeft.ScrollChange += _ScrollViewLeft_ScrollChange;
        _ScrollViewMedium.ScrollChange += _ScrollViewMedium_ScrollChange;
        _ScrollViewRight.ScrollChange += _ScrollViewRight_ScrollChange;

    }

    private void _ScrollViewLeft_ScrollChange(object sender, ScrollChangeEventArgs e)
    {

        int ScrollX = _ScrollViewLeft.ScrollX;
        int ScrollY = _ScrollViewLeft.ScrollY;
        _ScrollViewMedium.ScrollTo(ScrollX, ScrollY);
        _ScrollViewRight.ScrollTo(ScrollX, ScrollY);
    }
    private void _ScrollViewMedium_ScrollChange(object sender, ScrollChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        int ScrollX = _ScrollViewMedium.ScrollX;
        int ScrollY = _ScrollViewMedium.ScrollY;
        _ScrollViewLeft.ScrollTo(ScrollX, ScrollY);
        _ScrollViewRight.ScrollTo(ScrollX, ScrollY);
    }
    private void _ScrollViewRight_ScrollChange(object sender, ScrollChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        int ScrollX = _ScrollViewRight.ScrollX;
        int ScrollY = _ScrollViewRight.ScrollY;
        _ScrollViewLeft.ScrollTo(ScrollX, ScrollY);
        _ScrollViewMedium.ScrollTo(ScrollX, ScrollY);
    }
```